# Responsive design for icons in hybrid mobile app

Tags: android, css, html, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I am creating a hybrid mobile game suitable for both tablets and mobile phones. I have used the jQuery mobile 1.4.5 themeroller icons in my app. How do I increase the icons' size for tablets? The icons appear in the html5 portion of the app.

Also, the game has a table in the middle of the screen which appears squarish in mobile phones, but becomes non-squarish in tablets. The width of the table is set to 55% using CSS. How to make a square table for all the different dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

make sure to provide suitable icon resources for drawable-xxhdpi and drawable-xxxhdpi folders. More in http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Comment: Thanks @BarezBarznji for your comment! However, to clarify, my icons are in the html5 portion of the app, so I don't know how to make it work using the drawable folders. What is the way to do it when the icons are used in html5?